# Extraction Specific Lines From A Website

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
</span>
                    <div class="clearB paddingT5px"></div>
                    <small>
                        10/12/2015 5:49:00 PM -  Seeking Alpha
                    </small>
                    <div class="clearB paddingT10px"></div>
```

Suppose i have a source code of a website, a part of which looks like this. I am trying to get the line between "small" and "/small". In the entire webpage there are many such lines, enveloped between "small" and "/small". i want to extract all lines which are between "small" and "/small".

I am trying to use a 'regex' function which looks like this

```
regex = '<small>(.+?)</small>'
datestamp = re.compile(regex)
urls = re.findall(datestamp, htmltext)
```

This returns only a blank space. Please advise me on this.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regex? Use an HTML parser!

Comment: Try (.+) instead. Your regex is `lazy`.

Comment: BeautifulSoup select or find_all methods much more efficient

Comment: Although I agree with jonrsharpe. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5388440

Comment: Here ? http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways you could approach this:

Firstly using a regular expression, not recommended:

```
import re

html = """</span>
    <div class="clearB paddingT5px"></div>
    <small>
        10/12/2015 5:49:00 PM -  Seeking Alpha
    </small>
    <div class="clearB paddingT10px"></div>"""

for item in re.findall('\<small\>\s*(.*?)\s*\<\/small\>', html, re.I+re.M):
    print '"{}"'.format(item)
```

Secondly using something like `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML for you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for item in soup.find_all("small"):
    print '"{}"'.format(item.text.strip())
```

Giving the following output for both:

```
"10/12/2015 5:49:00 PM -  Seeking Alpha"
```

Answer (score 0):

use xml.etree here.  With that you can take the html data from the webpage and return whatever tag you wish using urllib2.....like so.

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree

url = whateverwebpageyouarelookingin
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Accept" : "application/xml"})
u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
tree = ElementTree.parse(u)
rootElem = tree.getroot()
yourdata = rootElem.findall("small")  
print yourdata
```